# The error message "address already in use ::: 8000" why

Tags: port

The error message "address already in use ::: 8000" indicates that something is already using port 8000 on your computer. This could be another program running in the background, such as a web server or a database.

How can fix it this error?

Comment: If using Linux run `netstat -tlnp` command to find the process having bind to that port & kill the process with `kill` or `pkill` utility. On Windows you could google to find relevant utilities.